# Teffilin and women

Tags: history, women, tefilin

Rashi's daughters are popularly described as having worn Teffilin, but [apparently](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/27823/rashis-daughters-wearing-tefillin) there is no such source, just a popular urban legend in Jewish circles. Are there any women described in Rabbinic sources as wearing Teffilin and what is the primary Rabbinic source for those descriptions?

Answer (score 14):

Michal the daughter of Shaul HaMelech wore Tefilin (Rashi to [Eruvin 96a](https://www.sefaria.org/Eruvin.96a.13))

http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9B%D7%9C

> לפי תלמוד בבלי מסכת עירובין צו. מיכל בת שאול הניחה תפלין. האר"י מסביר
>   זאת בכך שהייתה לה נשמה מעלמא דדכורא = נשמה מעולם הזכרים

Comment: it would be beneficial to add the Levush 17:2 who explains why Michal was an exception since she was a bas melech(however,the Eliyahu Zuta disagrees to his reasoning )

Comment: @Sam: You can add on to the answer.

Comment: @sam I thought all Jewish women were bnos melech.

Answer (score 2):

R. Avigdor Tzarfati (פירושים ופסקים לרבינו אביגדור צרפתי פסק ריג) records that some righteous women would don tefillin with a beracha.

> ומטעם זה נהגו מקצת נשים צדקניות להניח תפילין ולברך ולהתעטף בציצית

R. Joseph Messas (Nachalas Avos 5:2 Derush # 408) records that he saw written that in certain places in Spain the learned women would get together to pray, and some of them would don tefillin.

> ונרחיב עוד הדברים בזה כי דרך הנשים הכשרות לקום בהשכמה קודם בעליהן
>   ומכינות להם קאפ"י ואח"כ מעוררים אותם לעמוד לעבודת בראם ומושיטים להם
>   כוס של קאפי חם כדי לכונן דעתם לכוון בתפלתם וכמ"ש עליהן המלך שלמה ותקם
>   בעוד לילה ותתן טרף לביתה וחק לנערותיה דהיינו מכינה מזונות לביתה ועיקר
>   ביתה הוא בעלה ומכינה עוד חק לנערותיה העובדות אצלה בצמר בכל מיני עבודתו
>   נפוץ וכבוס וטויה ושזירה ואריגה שכאשר יבואו בבקר תמצא מה שראוי לה לעבוד
>   מוכן לפניה וראיתי על ספר כי באיזה  מקומות בספרד היו הנשים הכשרות
>   המלומדות קמות בהשכמה גדולה לביהכ"נ שלהן והיו מתפללות בצבור ואחת מהנה
>   היו מקימות לשליחא  דצבורא והיו מוציאות ס"ת ויש שהיו מניחות גם תפלין
>   וכל אחת היתה עטופה טלית וכן היו עושות גם בשבתות גם בימים טובים ואח"כ
>   היו חוזרין לבתיהן ומעוררין בעליהן ובניהם לעמוד להתפלל וזה היו עשוין
>   מצד החומרא על עצמן מפני שהנשים פטורית פטורות ממצות עשה שהזמן גרמא כדי
>   שיהיו פנויים להכין הצריך לבעליהם ולכן היו הן מקדימין להתפלל בעוד בעלהן
>   ישנים

Comment: don tefillin with a beracha... for tzitzit??

Comment: @DoubleAA In English it would be better punctuated, but he's saying two separate things: 1) They would don tefillin with a beracha. 2) They would enwrap themselves with tzitzis. This is as opposed to reading it as saying that they would don tefillin with the blessing of lehis'atef b'tzitzis.

Comment: Alternatively there's a typo and he meant some women don _tzitzit_ and say the blessing on tzitzit

Comment: @DoubleAA Unlikely for two reasons: 1) "ומטעם זה" is referring back to what he wrote immediately prior, which is that women can do any mitzvah they are exempt from such as tzitzis, tefillin, and re'iyas panim, with a beracha, and he proves this from Michal who wore tefillin, and Yonah's wife who was oleh l'regel. Tefillin features heavily in this context and therefore is probably not a mistake in the next sentence. 2) There would have to be a double typo - switching tefillin for tzitzis and also adding the "ו" in ולהתעטף, because the beracha for tzitzis would just be להתעטף.