# Do spirits/souls have genders?

Tags: women, men-male, soul, gender

Bodies have genders (physical anatomy and genetics) and the brain has a gender (gender identity), but do the spirits/souls or our heavenly bodies have genders as well?

Similar:

- [Do we retain our gender in Heaven?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/11549/do-we-retain-our-gender-in-heaven) at Christianity

Comment: The Magid Mesharim (written by the Beis Yosef; lessons with a malach) discusses someone who could not have children, and the BY explained that they both had female *neshamos* and therefore could not bear children; he prayed for them and somehow *kabbalistically* changed the feminine attributes to masculine, and they were able to have children.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Zohar writes that the Patriarch Yitzchok had the soul of a female.

Additionally, the Arizal explained that [Michal wore tefillin because she had a male soul](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/6034/472).

So it seems that souls do have genders, both male and female.

Comment: . . . and that they are not necessarily those of the bodies that possess them.

Comment: This may indicate the same ,Mishna Brurah 23:5 ה) של קבר - ואפילו בקבר של קטן יש להחמיר משום לועג לרש דשמא נשמת אדם גדול הוא אבל בקבר אשה דבחייה ג"כ פטורה ליכא משום לועג לרש:

Comment: where in the zohar?

Answer (score 5):

No. A soul is a spiritual entity and has no gender. However according to Kabbalah there are two worlds where souls can come from. A "Masculine" world and a "Feminine" world. The Lubavitcher Rebbe Z"L explains that that

> the way of a soul from the "masculine side" is to transform the world
>   by being pro-active and outgoing, while the path of the soul from the
>   "feminine side" is to accept the world as it is, trying to live
>   properly according to Torah, but without trying to influence the
>   world.

So when the Kabbala uses those terms it does so as a metaphor to explain a concept not to indicate gender.

Note when explaining Michal the daughter of Shaul the holy Ari says that she had a

> נשמה **מעלמא** דדכורא

loosely translated as "She had a soul from the world of the masculine (side)" Not that her soul was of the male gender.

I encourage you to read the whole article from the Chabad website - [Female and Male Souls](http://www.chabad.org/kabbalah/article_cdo/aid/1665517/jewish/Female-and-Male-Souls.htm)

Comment: I don't see a distinction between saying a soul has a gender and saying the soul has masculine qualities or feminine qualities (especially on a question that has gender identity in it, so it already understands we aren't being literal about reproductive organs).

Comment: I understood the question as "are there boy souls and girl souls ?" which there are not. Souls have no gender. They are neither male or female although they can have the male/female traits as described by the rebbe.
Perhaps the person who asked the question will give us a better idea of what he meant ? I would gladly erase my answer if I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 1):

the shemonei shearim shaar gilgulim (forget exact place) says that if a male soul is reincarnated in a female body, as sometimes happens, then that female cannot have a male child - only female children, as the verse says in parsha tazria "when a woman conceives and bears a male child", and that woman is really a man in a female body.

I think he says there that male soul are from adam while female souls are from chava.

Comment: But the Rashi says ([Shmuel 2 3:5](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15863#showrashi=true&v=5)) that Michal Bat Shaul had a baby boy and the Ari said that she had a male soul. Hence this must be inaccurate.

Comment: It's Shaar Gilgulim 9:2. Chabad translation and commentary here: https://www.chabad.org/kabbalah/article_cdo/aid/380899/jewish/Cross-Gender-Soul-Migration-92.htm