# Why can a deceased woman be called to the Torah?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

We wish that a deceased person is called to the Torah, whether a man or a woman, when we say *the neshamah should have an aliyah*. While I understand that a man can be called to the torah, since he was called to the torah while he was alive, how can a woman now be called to the torah, when she was not called when she was alive.

Note this does not address the question as to how the meis can say the bracha to begin with and how we can answer amen.

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Answer (score 2):

Women can be called to the Torah provided "*kavod tzibbur*" is maintained. As a result, when she dead and there is no such issue, she can be called up.

However dead people should not be given aliyos as they cannot donate any money. The only exception is if they promised the money in their will.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that in *Neshamo* there is no distinction between male and female, only in the *Guf*. (Might seem to be a too serious answer for Purim Torah!) :-)

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/53114