# the Alter Rebbe's daughter had a male soul

Tags: sources-mekorot, historical-figures, hasidic-story

What is the source that the Alter Rebbe's daughter (Fraida) had a male soul?

I heard in a shiur that the alter rebbe said that his daughter has a male soul (I guess similar to [this](http://www.chabad.org/380899/))

Is this true (that he said this or something similar to it)? Source please

(what does it mean?)

Comment: Closely related, but more general: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/53114/3

Comment: That's why I don't vmeet many chassidish girls on Saw You At Sinai - because the Arizal holds that the girls around today weren't at Sinai!

Comment: See also http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/6034

Comment: @ClintEastwood Wow really? Elaborate! I've never heard that the Arizal held this.

Comment: @ezra he might be misrepresenting by connecting the idea of girls not having gilgulim with the idea that everyone was at har-sinai

Comment: @hazoriz well wouldn't that be a correct inference then?

Comment: @ezra (until he shows a source) to me it seems possible that the soul of an unborn Jewish girl was there and was born 2 thousand years after that **for the first time** (not a gilgul) . Also I do not think the arizal argues with the gemara https://www.sefaria.org/Shevuot.39a.9 and https://www.sefaria.org/Shabbat.146a.1 , and the midrash quoted by rashi https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Deuteronomy.29.14.

Comment: @hazoriz very good very good!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comment is found on page 193 from Sefer Yamei Chabad.

But looking at the language, it doesn’t appear to be discussing reincarnation (גלגול).

It mentions that the Alter Rebbe once said that the *Neshamah* of his daughter, Fraida was connected to עולם דדוכרא. It says that the Alter Rebbe commented that for whatever reason, that *Neshamah* was dressed in the body of his daughter.

This comment was in the context that the Alter Rebbe taught his daughter, Fraida, Chassidic discourses.

In context, that seems to be saying that her intellect was masculine. It is not talking about reincarnation.

Comment: @hazoriz The comment is on [p. 179](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=15863&st=&pgnum=179&hilite=) I disagree with YaacovD though and think that even given the context, the Alter Rebbe was speaking of her soul in toto, not only her intellect.

Comment: @Oliver thank you and I agree with you (did Fraida have children?) related ואין ראיה ממיכל בת שאול שהיתה מנחת תפילין, ע"כ. והביאו יפה ללב ז"ל אות ב' וכתב, דמה שכתב: "ואין ראיה ממיכל בת שאול" וכו', אפשר לומר דמיכל בת שאול היתה אשה חכמה וידעה בעצמה שהיתה לה **נשמה מעלמא דדכורא**, ולכך ולמיכל בת שאול לא היה לה ולד, עכ"ל. ועיין שער הגלגולים הקדמה ט' שכתב, שאשה שמגולגל בה נשמת זכר אי אפשר לה להתעבר, אם לא על ידי זכות גדול שתתעבר בה איזה נשמת אשה נקבה אחרת בסוד עיבור וכו', יעו"ש. ועיין מה שכתבתי לעיל סימן טו"ב אות ה': from כף החיים  38.3

Comment: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%9C%D7%97_%D7%92#%D7%98_%D7%9B%D7%94%D7%97

Comment: @hazoriz Per the שער הגלגולים, yes, her son was [R. Aaron of Kremenchuk](http://chabadpedia.co.il/index.php/אהרן_זסלבסקי_מקרמנצ%27וג) . (Don't ask me for a reconciliation :) )

Comment: @Oliver  there was another son רבי ברוך, according to this http://chabadpedia.co.il/index.php/אליהו_(חתן_אדמו"ר_הזקן)

Comment: @Oliver You don’t understand the language the Alter Rebbe is using (עולם דדכורא). He is referring to her refinement, not reincarnation. See discussion of the concept from Machshavot Charutz 8:13. https://www.sefaria.org/Machshavot_Charutz.8?vhe=R%27_Zadok_--_Machshavot_Charutz&lang=bi

Comment: @YaacovDeane This is pointless. For each of your [late Chassidus] sources I can counter with a cryptic passage in an older kabbalistic source. Can you conclusively prove what the Alter Rebbe meant? (Also, would you please briefly explain, in comprehensible English, the difference between refinement and reincarnation, and then point to a source (Hebrew/Aramaic would be acceptable) for said differentiation?)

Comment: @Oliver The nomenclature is different between kabbalah and Chassidut. If you are trying to understand a particular usage, it requires seeing how it is applied in context. In general, the Alter Rebbe used the nomenclature of Chassidut. A possible proof relates to Rebbetzin Fraida having children, which according to your view shouldn’t have happened. FYI, this phenomenon of a male being born in a female body and being sterile is understood today. It is the rare situation of XXY females. Another external indicator is that they are very well endowed physically.

Comment: I believe it is called Androgen Insensitivity Syndrome.

Comment: @YaacovDeane Agreed, the nomenclature is sometimes unique, but the concepts originate from Kabbalah. And in this particular context it can easily be understood the way hazoriz and I understand. I'm familiar with the science but let not kid ourselves and read too much into this.

Comment: My reason for mentioning it is in the context of Fraida having children. Like the Ari z”l mentions, this type of incarnation would be sterile.

Comment: @YaacovDeane I understand. But without having to revert to such far-fetched interpretations, it's easier (and more sensible) to say, perhaps, 1) Ari was mistaken, 2) Ari meant it generally, 3) Frieda had a double transmigration which included a male, 4) she was granted a spiritual/physical tikkun, 5) Alter Rebbe was mistaken about his daughter's soul. (I sincerely hope I did not offend you by 1 & 5; it's for the sake of rationalization.)

Comment: @Oliver no offense taken. We’re talking. If not considering who made the statement, your points 2-4 are valid. But it ignores a general teaching from all the Rebbes of Chabad about the nature of their publicized (and printed) stories. They are not about revealing private, personal matters. They are only to inspire & to teach proper service of HaShem. That means this comment about his daughter which was publicized is meant in that context. The way you are understanding it, that he is revealing a negative (& private) personal spiritual detail is contrary to his teachings.